# What happens when two people commit to a GitHub repo?

Tags: git, github

Just a theoretical basis I'm trying to understand here - when two people are working on a GitHub project from its original form ("commited the same repository"?), what happens when they each make changes, for example to the same line, and then both upload the changed files ("forking"?)

Does one overwrite the previous person's changes? First time using git, I've read the intro book about the structure of VCSs but just wondering how this is handled.

Comment: It's not forking. Their commits will be merged.

Comment: read Pro Git, [http://git-scm.com/book](http://git-scm.com/book)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Same thing that would happen if two people commit on any other server, their changes are merged together by the last person who pushes (the server does not do any merging, it's all done by the users!).

Usually if they both modify the same line then a few things could happen:

- The user that didn't commit his change yet will need to stash his changes or merge his changes when he pulls from the server
- The more recent change is the one committed (if that user pulled before he made his change)

Regardless, git handles merging very well and will do it automagically most of the time.  When you do need to do it manually git kind of walks you through it.

Comment: What if the changes are big though, and only some of the lines are changed in each? Isn't this a bad setup for collaboration?

Comment: It gets merged.  If you want collaboration, you should use some form of version control.  Git is one of the more popular ones.  They all essentially do the same thing, just in different ways and some are more efficient than others.

Comment: Cheers Matt, still reading the documentation but your answer helps

Comment: To clarify, your answer makes it sounds like "their changes are merged together" by the server.  In fact, one of the users would have to merge these changes and then push the resultant merge.

Comment: I think I'll just use the VSCode extension called [Liveshare](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare).

I'm just thinking if the first person added something, then the second person removed of the same text in a code file, how would that work?